# How to pass variables in URL while getting data from backend in angular?

Tags: angular, url, httpclient

```
public getQuestionsById(qid:number): Observable<Questions>{
 return this.httpClient.get<Questions> 
  ('http://localhost:9090/angular/questions/${qid}');
  
}
```

Here, I want to concatenate the "qid" variable value in this URL. What should be the right format for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use Template literals for that. Check the basics you are just using wrong operator. please not use [single quote](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/singquot.htm) here, use [backquot](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/backquot.htm) for that.

```
public getQuestionsById(qid:number): Observable<Questions>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Questions>(`http://localhost:9090/angular/questions/${qid}`);
     
   }
```

Best of luck :)

link : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

I personally do this :

```
public getQuestionsById(qid:number): Observable<Questions>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Questions>("http://localhost:9090/angular/questions/" + qid);  
   }
```

Also a quick tip, instead of writing that URL in every single Service file, add a variable in the environment file, then you can import it anywhere you need it
(in case you are using this in more Services, of course).